# SQL server compability level issue - disabled

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2000

I have one database named `TransportDB` whose compatibility level is set to `SQL Server 2000 (80)`. I want to change the compatibility level of this DB to `SQL Server 2005 (90)` or `2008 (100)`, but when I go to change this using Properties-->Options-->Compatibility level, I found that this compatibility level option is disabled i.e. I can't change the compatibility level.

I want to know how to change compatibility level and if I will change it, will this effect my current database or records in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this SQL

```
EXEC sp_dbcmptlevel @dbname = 'TransportDB', @new_cmptlevel = 90;
```

You can use different values for `@new_cmptlevel` of course.

Comment: if i will change compatibility level,will this effect my current DB or records?

Comment: yes, it may have some effects on your db. you should read this -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510680.aspx